# How to set initial weights in MLPClassifier?

Tags: scikit-learn, neural-network

I cannot find a way to set the initial weights of the neural network, could someone tell me how please?
I am using python package sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.

Here is the code for reference:

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
classifier = MLPClassifier(solver="sgd")
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 6):

**Solution**:
A working solution is to inherit from MLPClassifier and override the _init_coef method. In the _init_coef write the code to set the initial weights.
Then use the new class *"MLPClassifierOverride"* as in the example below instead of *"MLPClassifier"*

```
# new class
class MLPClassifierOverride(MLPClassifier):
# Overriding _init_coef method
def _init_coef(self, fan_in, fan_out):
    if self.activation == 'logistic':
        init_bound = np.sqrt(2. / (fan_in + fan_out))
    elif self.activation in ('identity', 'tanh', 'relu'):
        init_bound = np.sqrt(6. / (fan_in + fan_out))
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unknown activation function %s" %
                         self.activation)
    coef_init = ### place your initial values for coef_init here

    intercept_init = ### place your initial values for intercept_init here

    return coef_init, intercept_init
```

Answer (score 5):

The [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html) show you the attributes in use.

> Attributes:
>   ...
>
> `coefs_` : list, length n_layers - 1
>   The ith element in the list represents the weight matrix corresponding to > layer i.
>
> `intercepts_` : list, length n_layers - 1
>   The ith element in the list represents the bias vector corresponding to layer > i + 1.

Just build your classifier `clf=MLPClassifier(solver="sgd")` and set `coefs_` and `intercepts_` before calling `clf.fit()`.

The only remaining question is: does sklearn overwrite your inits?

The [code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/neural_network/multilayer_perceptron.py#L345) looks like:

```
    if not hasattr(self, 'coefs_') or (not self.warm_start and not
                                       incremental):
        # First time training the model
        self._initialize(y, layer_units)
```

This looks to me like it won't replace your given `coefs_` (you might check biases too).

The packing and unpacking [functions](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/neural_network/multilayer_perceptron.py#L77) further indicates that this should be possible. These are probably used for serialization through pickle internally.

Comment: This does not work, I tried this already. it does not overwrite before you call the fit function. I found a working solution I will post it in the comment.

Comment: @MohamedElSheikh could you post your solution?

Comment: Hey @Jeremy, yes, I posted a working solution below.

Answer (score 1):

`multilayer_perceptron.py` initializes the weights based on the nonlinear function used for hidden layers. If you want to try a different initialization, you can take a look at the function `_init_coef` [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f3320a6f/sklearn/neural_network/multilayer_perceptron.py#L300-L316) and modify as you desire.