# Initialize weights in sklearn.neural_network

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, initialization

I want to initialize weights in a MLPclassifier, but when i use sample_weight in `.fit()` method, 
it says that `TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sample_weight'`

```
import sklearn.neural_network as SKNN

mlp_classifier = SKNN.MLPClassifier((10,), learning_rate="invscaling",solver="lbfgs")

fit_model = mlp_classifier.fit(train_data,train_target,  sample_weight = weight)
```

i also read [What does `sample_weight` do to the way a `DecisionTreeClassifier` works in sklearn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34389624/what-does-sample-weight-do-to-the-way-a-decisiontreeclassifier-works-in-skle), it said that you should use sample_weight in the `.fit()` method.

is there any way to use `sample_weight` for `MLPclassifier` like the one used in `Decisiontreeclassifier` ?

Answer (score 1):

That is because `MLPClassifier` unlike `DecisionTreeClassifier` doesn't have a `fit()` method with a `sample_weight` parameter.

See [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.fit).

Maybe some of the answers to this similar question can help:
[How to set initial weights in MLPClassifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44478133/5792352)

Comment: is there any way to use something like `sample_weight` for `MLPclassifier` like the one used in `Decisiontreeclassifier` ?

Comment: I don't think so - not unless one of the suggested work-arounds in the link I gave works. You might consider using Keras instead, as shown here: https://towardsdatascience.com/hyper-parameters-in-action-part-ii-weight-initializers-35aee1a28404.

Comment: Also, you might be able to get something useful out of this conversation about adding a pre-training functionality from scikit's Github page: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/3281

Answer (score 0):

according to [sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.fit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.fit) the `fit` method does not have an argument named `sample_weight`

Answer (score 0):

There are no sample weights in sklearn NN yet. But you can as the start:

1. find it in Keras: https://keras.io/models/sequential/
2. write the NN in numpy and implement sample_weight by yourself